# How to install a recent version of cmake on Centos5?

Tags: python, cmake, python-wheel

I am trying to generate python wheels of my python project, which depends on CMake >= 2.8.12. This has to be done on an old linux distro, CentOS5, for compatibility reasons (for details check [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux)). `yum install cmake` gives me: `cmake version 2.6-patch 4`, which is quite old.

Comment: Sounds like you should compile it from source. or run a container/virtual machine on your old OS (I can see reasons for using older OS:es). I feel obligated to point out that CentOS5 is end of life since two years ago.

Comment: Torxed: No need to compile it, just pip install it. OTOH if you could post an answer with details on how to successfully build it you would get my upvote. Perhaps you could share a Dockerfile?

Comment: Installing a binary through pip just sounds dirty. But it's for sure one way to do it, and on such an old system I doubt it will make a difference how you solve it - as long as you solve it :)

Comment: I understand the title of the question is a bit generic, but those that read the question will see that it is in the context of creating a python build (wheel), so it makes total sense to use pip in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there are cmake wheels available on PyPI. So simply run:

```
pip install cmake
```

and you will get the latest version available in the [index](https://pypi.org/project/cmake/#files).

It is worth noting that the `cmake` binary is installed in its respective python bin directory. So if you run:

```
/opt/python/cp35-cp35m/bin/pip install cmake
```

the `cmake` binary will be installed in:

```
/opt/python/cp35-cp35m/bin/cmake
```